# How far can Spectral Algebraic Geometry be developed over $\mathbb{E}_2$-rings (instead of $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-rings)?

Tags: homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

Jacob Lurie has extensively developed derived algebraic geometry in the setting of $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-ring spectra [[SAG]](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/SAG-rootfile.pdf). The resulting theory of Spectral Algebraic Geometry (SAG) gives (in particular) a way to view some of the spectra topologists care about algebro-geometrically, as spectral schemes. In particular, examples of such spectra would be

1. The complex cobordism spectrum $\mathrm{MU}$;
2. Complex $K$-theory $\mathrm{KU}$;
3. The spectrum $\mathrm{TMF}$ of topological modular forms;
4. The sphere spectrum $\mathbb{S}$.

On the other hand, there are many important spectra which don't admit $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-structures (and hence don't fit in Lurie's SAG) such as:

1. The $p$-local Brown-Peterson spectrum $\mathrm{BP}$ and its connective covers $\rm{BP}\langle n\rangle$;
2. The Morava $K$-theories $K(n)$;
3. The Ravenel spectra $X(n)$.

There has been work on SAG over $\mathbb{E}_n$-rings, in particular by John Francis, in his [thesis](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~jnkf/writ/thezrev.pdf). Focusing on  $n=2$, what results of SAG are expected to be troublesome to extend to the setting of $\mathbb{E}_2$-ring spectra?

---

I'm also tempted to ask here Sanath's question on this topic:

> [...] what are some results in either the purely algebro-geometric or purely chromatic aspects of spectral algebraic geometry which rely upon using the entire $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-ring structure?

to be found in his [A love letter to E_2-rings](https://sanathdevalapurkar.github.io/algebraic-topology/2019/06/06/ode.html).

---

@crystalline raised two interesting questions in the comments:

> [...] what results of SAG does one actually want in the E_2-setting? and what are some concrete things those results would buy you?

Comment: Not quite what you are asking for, but if $E$ is only a $E_2$-ring, then $E$-modules have only a monoidal structure (and not a symmetric monoidal structure)

Comment: let me ask a different question, what results of SAG does one actually *want* in the E_2-setting? and what are some concrete things those results would buy you?

Comment: a lot of the results in Lurie's book just go through word for word, the only thing you really have to be careful about is the tensor product-- it's not the same as the coproduct in the category of E_2-algebras!

Comment: Haha, didn't think my blog would show up on MathOverflow! Two comments: first, the obstruction theory for E_∞-rings is a lot better than that of E_k-rings for 1<k<∞, because for E_k-rings, one enters "bracket hell" (a term I learnt from Tyler Lawson); and second (relatedly), as I wrote at the end of the linked post, E_∞-power operations in chromatic homotopy theory have a nice algebro-geometric interpretation, but I don't know of anything similar for E_2-power operations. Note that the pure braid group is infinite.

Comment: @DenisNardin That's nice to know! What happens for modules over $E_k$-rings for other $k$? Do they get braided monoidal structures or something similar?

Comment: The (∞-)category of modules over an E_k-ring admits an E_{k-1}-monoidal structure.

Comment: @crystalline These are nice questions! I mentioned them (now, in an edit) in the question too.

Comment: @skd Those are nice to know too! Would you recommend some particular references for these? (That is, obstruction theory for $E_\infty$-rings and $E_\infty$-power operations in chromatic homotopy theory, both classically and via SAG?)

Comment: @skd and thank you for answering my $E_k$-modules question!

Comment: For certain things it might make more sense to use E_k-modules instead of left modules. Two reasons for this: (1) the category of E_k-modules over an E_k ring is still E_k monoidal, so you don’t get this loss of monoidality that others were pointing out; (2) deformations of E_k rings are controlled by the E_k-cotangent complex which is an E_k-module not a left module. (When k=infty you get this nice fact that left modules agree with E_infty-modules).

Comment: For the obstruction theory of structured ring spectra, you should check out Goerss-Hopkins (see Goerss' webpage), as well as the Talbot 2017 notes (http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/2017/talbot-notes-2017.pdf). For E_oo-power operations in the chromatic setting, check out work of Rezk (in particular, his talk slides titled "Power operations in Morava E-theory: a survey"). As for this stuff in SAG: afaik, there's no source talking about a purely SAG-construction of power operations, but it is implicit in the height 2 case in the construction of tmf...

Comment: ... which you can find in Behrens' notes on the construction of tmf. Regarding obstruction theory in SAG: part of the point of SAG is to obtain these highly structured "designer" ring spectra (like Lubin-Tate theory, KO, TMF) "without obstruction theory", but rather via spectrifying the moduli problems in classical algebraic geometry used to define the algebraic analogues of these ring spectra.

Comment: @skd Wow! Thank you for the references (and also for taking notes in the 2017 Talbot with Eva Belmont, these look incredible)!